# Compare local text file with server text file

Tags: java, android, webserver

I have a file on my server called "questions.txt" where questions are stored. In my app i have a raw res folder where there is also a "questions.txt". I have a few things i want to do, and have no idea how:

1. Prevent the user from editing the text file himself with a file explorer
2. On app start, compare the local text file with the server one and update the local one if necessary.
3. Obviously make everything as safe as possible.

I hope you can help me or give me an idea on how to achieve this.

Dave

Comment: Instead of comparing the local text file with the server one each time, you can just download the text file from the server each time...Isnt it the best idea?

Comment: That's a good idea for 2., thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: You cannot really prevent this if the user has root permissions unless you find a way to encrypt the data and manage to hide the implementation of the app to decrypt it.

2: If the file is pretty big you could make a hash of the file and compare that to a server side hash of the file to save data transmitted.

3: Don't use a plain HTTP connection again, look for ways of encryption and decryption. HTTPS would be suitable for this.

Comment: Thanks, I already use HTTPS. Are you sure there is no way for 1 to work? Otherwise the app would need an active internet connection :(

Comment: @DaveLillo You could check if the user has a rooted phone and deny usage of the app, then delete the txt file as soon as the user exits the app to prevent the user from installing the app and then rooting. But I don't know if this is a secure approach at all.